# fnd_ldap_wrapper.update_user exception while using fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER oracle apps api

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps

We are trying to update the users using the fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER and getting the below error. The API is called from the custom procedure

```
create or replace procedure change_name as 
begin 

fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER ( 
 x_user_name => 'ALDELEON',
x_owner => 'CUST',
 x_description => 'dragonssss'
);

END;

/

SHOW ERRORS;

SQL> exec change_name
BEGIN change_name; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Unable to update user ALDELEON with userid 5523 for the following
reason: Unabled to call fnd_ldap_wrapper.update_user due to the following
reason:
ORA-20001: Unabled to call fnd_ldap_wrapper.update_user due to the following
reason:
An unexpected error occurred. Please contact your System Administrator.
(USER_NAME=ALDELEON). (USER_NAME=ALDELEON).
ORA-06512: at "APPS.APP_EXCEPTION", line 72
ORA-06512: at "APPS.FND_USER_PKG", line 570
ORA-06512: at "APPS.FND_USER_PKG", line 1811
ORA-06512: at "APPS.CHANGE_NAME", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

For the same user when the fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER  is called from anonymous block is updating fine

```
begin 

fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER ( 
 x_user_name => 'ALDELEON',
x_owner => 'CUST',
 x_description => 'dragonssss'
);

END;
```

Please note both the procedure and anonymous block is called from APPS schema. The procedure is also compiled in the APPS schema

Any idea if there is a setup that needs to be done to execute the API from a procedure.

We are on Oracle Apps R12.2 technology stack

Comment: Anonymous block is executed by the same user APPS?

Comment: yes. the anonymous block is executed by APPS.

Comment: Is the user end dated within OID? Did you try removing the end_date of this user in OIDAS?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Initialize the user_id, responsibility_id and responsiblity_application_id with correct values.

```
create or replace procedure change_name
 as 
  ln_user_id NUMBER := '124';
  ln_resp_id NUMBER := '1234';
   ln_resp_appl_id NUMBER := '12';
begin 

fnd_global.apps_initialize(ln_user_id,ln_resp_id,ln_resp_appl_id);

 fnd_user_pkg.UPDATEUSER ( 
   x_user_name => 'ALDELEON',
   x_owner => 'CUST',
    x_description => 'dragonssss'
   ); 
     commit;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error: '|| sqlerrm);

    END;
```